# Magento 2 How to interchange positions of block-search and minicart

Tags: magento2, frontend

Magento 2 How to interchange positions of block-search and mini-cart in front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using custom theme then try changing below file

> app/design/frontend/Your_vendor/Theme_name/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<move element="minicart" destination="header-wrapper" after="top.search"/>
```

OR

```
<move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" after="minicart"/>
```

You can put this line anywhere inside body tag.After changing file flush the magento cache

Answer (score 1):

You should use a custom theme. There in your theme create a file called default.xml under YOURTHEME/Magento_Theme/layout/
and then edit it like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <body>
   <move element="minicart" destination="header-wrapper" after="top.search"/>
 </body>
</page>
```

Remember to flush cache,
bin/magento cache:flush